# Debugging TemplateNotFound postmortem django 1.9

Tags: python, django

Been couple days of trying to get my template loaded in view - keep getting error in subj. Here is postmortem http://pastebin.com/JJCtPyYj You can see in there TEMPLATE_DIRS being defined. Tried django 1.10, 1.9.9, 1.8.7. Any clues on how to further debug this annoyance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

TEMPLATE_DIRS is not relevant, and has not been since Django 1.8. As you can see from the traceback, the relevant setting is the DIRS part of TEMPLATES, and that is empty: you need to put the directories in there.